# og:image meta tag is not found by LinkedIn and Facebook

Tags: html, image, meta-tags

I got a problem with my og meta tags. All my og meta tags are read by LinkedIn, Facebook, and all the other which use the og meta tags.

I used https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/https:%2F%2Fkellis.fr%2F to see if my meta tags was read. And all my og meta tags are read except the image. Even the og:image is visible on my website.

You can verify on https://kellis.fr/, it's available!
The website https://www.opengraph.xyz/url/https%3A%2F%2Fkellis.fr%2F/ tell me that it is available.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LinkedIn and Facebook don't take WEBP images into account. I fixed that by changing my image into a PNG image and it works !